# Changing the xticks for x axis in scatterplot

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot

I'm plotting a scatter plot and would like to have the a-axis as entry named than index. My data is from MASS in R and looks like this

```
animals={'Mountain beaver';'Cow';'Grey wolf';'Goat';'Guinea pig';'Dipliodocus';'Asian elephant';'Donkey';'Horse';'Potar monkey';'Cat';'Giraffe';'Gorilla';'Human';'African elephant';'Triceratops';'Rhesus monkey';'Kangaroo';'Golden hamster';'Mouse';'Rabbit';'Sheep';'Jaguar';'Chimpanzee';'Rat';'Brachiosaurus';'Mole';'Pig'};

body=[1.35  465 36.33   27.66   1.04    11700   2547    187.1   521 10  3.3 529 207 62  6654    9400    6.8 35  0.12    0.023   2.5 55.5    100 52.16   0.28    87000   0.122   192];

brain=[8.1  423 119.5   115 5.5 50  4603    419 655 115 25.6    680 406 1320    5712    70  179 56  1   0.4 12.1    175 157 440 1.9 154.5   3   180];

% Plot
x=1:length(body);
scatter(x,body,'filled','d') 
hold
scatter(x,brain,'filled') 
legend('body', 'brain','location','east');
```

How could I amend the program so my scatterplot display animals in xticks with 45 degrees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
% add these lines at the end of your code
set(gca,'XTickLabel',animals)
set(gca,'XTick',1:numel(animals));
xlim([0 numel(animals)+1]);
set(gca, 'XTickLabelRotation', 45);
```

which gives this:

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly!